# Loop refresh page until selector is available

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I've got a script in casperjs that goes to a website checks a box if available and then click on a button to continue with the script.

right now I have a cronjob that exacutes this everysecond untill the checkbox is available. What I'd like to do is to execute the script and refresh the page until the checkbox is available.

I've tried doind a while loop but the script crashes, and I tried the repeat function, but is not ideal since I dont know how many times I have to try until the checkbox becomes available.

this is my script in case you need it:

```
casper.start(url1, function(){
    this.click('a[title="Chile"]');
});

casper.thenOpen(url2, function() {
    if(this.exists('#acepta_terminos')){ //this is where I check the checkbox
        seguir=false;
        this.click('#acepta_terminos');
        this.click('input[type="button"][name="continuar"]');

        this.waitForSelector('#contenedor', function(){
            this.fillSelectors('form[name="formulario"]',{
                '*[name="foid_tipo_1"]'                 :'NI', 
                '*[name="foid_numero_1"]'               :persona.rut,
            },true);

            this.click('#id_declaro_input');
            this.click('input[type="button"][name="continuar"]');
        });

        casper.then(function(){
            this.capture('4e.png');
        });
    } //cierre de if exists
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Your script looks strange. Are you sure the second of the first two `click`s actually works? Are you sure that the other two `click`s do anything, because you submit the form?

Comment: it works, I currently use it. all I want to do is instead of executing the script every second, i want to refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done recursively.

```
function check() {
    this.thenOpen(url2, function(){
        if(this.exists('#acepta_terminos')){
            seguir=false;
            this.click('#acepta_terminos');
            this.click('input[type="button"][name="continuar"]');

            this.waitForSelector('#contenedor', function(){
                this.fillSelectors('form[name="formulario"]',{
                    '*[name="foid_tipo_1"]'                 :'NI', 
                    '*[name="foid_numero_1"]'               :persona.rut,
                },true);

                this.click('#id_declaro_input');
                this.click('input[type="button"][name="continuar"]');
            });

            casper.then(function(){
                this.capture('4e.png');
            });
        } else {
            this.wait(5000, check);
        }
    });
}

casper.start(url1, function(){
    this.click('a[title="Chile"]');
}).then(check).run();
```

Note that inside of a function all of the asynchronous functions (`then*` and `wait*`) have to be executed after the synchronous functions (like `click`).